# Puppet selboolean module

Tags: selinux, puppet

I have the following puppet module:

```
 selboolean { 'scan system':
    name       => 'scan system',
    persistent => true,
    provider   => 'antivirus_can_scan_system',
    value      => on,
}
```

When I deploy the module, I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter provider failed on Selboolean[scan system]: Invalid selboolean provider 'antivirus_can_scan_system' at /file/path/selinux.pp

I am not really familiar with Puppet language, so I am not sure what's I am doing wrong here.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The values you give to your various attributes need to be what the system expects them to be.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/selboolean.html

> **name**
>
> (*Namevar: If omitted, this attribute’s value defaults to the resource’s title.*)
>
> The name of the SELinux boolean to be managed.
>
> **provider**
>
> The specific backend to use for this selboolean resource. You will seldom need to specify this — Puppet will usually discover the appropriate provider for your platform.

Try

```
selboolean { 'scan system':
    name       => 'antivirus_can_scan_system',
    persistent => true,
    value      => on,
}
```